# Filter using re module

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a list as presented below :

```
['\'STATE\\\': \\\'("DEVELOPMENT COMPLETE", "DEVELOPMENT IN PROGRESS", "WIP QA")\\\'}, \']']
```

Now I want to filter the part below , from the mentioned list using `re` module .

```
("DEVELOPMENT COMPLETE", "DEVELOPMENT IN PROGRESS", "WIP QA")
```

can anybody help me use `re` module?

Comment: Isn't that a list with just one element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :

```
>>> l = ['\'STATE\\\': \\\'("DEVELOPMENT COMPLETE", "DEVELOPMENT IN PROGRESS", "WIP QA")\\\'}, \']'] 
>>> re.search(r'(\([^\)]*\))' , l[0]).group(1)
'("DEVELOPMENT COMPLETE", "DEVELOPMENT IN PROGRESS", "WIP QA")'
```

And if you want your result as `tuple`, you can always use `ast`

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(re.search(r'(\([^\)]*\))', l[0]).group(1))
('DEVELOPMENT COMPLETE', 'DEVELOPMENT IN PROGRESS', 'WIP QA')
```

Just in case, if your list contains multiple elements then you might need to iterate it and then use above `re`

Comment: tnx , i will test and let u know

Comment: Glad to help :)